# Separate number from word in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following column in Excel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiiI2.png

All I want to do is to isolate the number of seconds (just number, without the "s") so I can calculate averages and sums normally. I tried some alternatives but I couldn't find a proper solution. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1)
```